# Create a dictionary from data separated by commas

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file named 'names.txt'. Each line of the file is in this format (year,name,gender,count). For example (1980,david,M,12).

I want to read each line and then seperate it into dictionaries named (year,name,gender,count). Everytime I run my program, it sets (year,name,gender,count) to the last thing that it reads, instead of adding it into the dictionary. Do I have to add an append to somewhere in my code so that it does what I want it to?

```
f = open('names.txt')
lines = 0
years = {}
names = {}
gender = {}
count = {}
for line in f:
    lines += 1
    years, names, gender, count = line.strip().split(",")
print(names)
return lines
```

Comment: Are you trying to add into dictionaries or lists?  I can see you are using dictionaries but what would you be using as the keys? I presume what you;re actually trying to do is append to lists?

Comment: I think you are right. Would I be better off making one dictionary with the values of (years, names, gender, and count) inside of it?

Comment: The real question is what do you want as your key and value?

Comment: See @Uriel Eli answer, second option on creating a dictionary of people

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are build for search by keys. By your current usage, it looks like you're looking for overlapping lists, because no of the fields has a key:

```
lines = 0
years, names, genders, counts = [], [], [], []
for line in f:
    year, name, gender, count = line.strip().split(",")
    years.append(year)
    names.append(name)
    genders.append(gender)
    counts.append(int(count))
    lines += 1
```

However, creating dictionar**y** makes sense in this case, when saving all the data under the key of the name:

```
lines = 0
people = {}
for line in f:
    year, name, gender, count = line.strip().split(",")
    people[name] = {'year': year, 'gender': gender, 'count': int(count)}
    lines += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this. using **defaultdict**

```
                from collections import defaultdict  
                f = open('names.txt')
                lines = 0

                d = defaultdict(list)

                for line in f:
                    year, name, gender, count = line.strip().split(",")
                    d[year].append((name,gender,count))
```

it depends on the data though.